# iOS - Obtaining localised system image

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uiimage, sf-symbols

I am referring to [SF Symbols app](https://developer.apple.com/sf-symbols/) for available system icons. If I have to use the asset, I could directly use the `systemName` to create `UIImage`. Recently I noticed that there is something called `Localisation` in SF Symbols app. But idea how could I convert this to code. For instance, if I have to use `Right-to-Left` localisation option of an asset in `UIImage`, how could this be done?

[image]

Comment: It would automatically change to the correct image if your app is localised to a RTL language and the device's language setting is also that language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the symbol as you normally would:

```
let image = UIImage(systemName: "rectangle.portrait.and.arrow.forward")
```

The actual direction of that symbol's arrow depends on the localizations your app supports and the user's chosen locale. If your app supports a right-to-left locale and the user has chosen that right-to-left locale then the arrow will point to the left.